# Why an empty Java app consumes memory?

Tags: java, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does an empty Java program consume memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361902/why-does-an-empty-java-program-consume-memory)

Why an absolutely empty Java application continuously consumes memory?
The app:

```
public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
            Thread.currentThread().wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Heap state:

[image: Empty Java app heap state]

Updated: IOException fix.

Comment: Is it possible that the act of you monitoring it is creating objects? Just a thought.

Comment: 1) Your program is not empty. 2) All running programs automatically get ***some*** amount of memory. For the minimum java heap size please refer to [this other SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-java-heap-size-determined).

Comment: Presumably System.in.read is doing stuff "under the covers".  Try Thread.wait instead.

Comment: +1 BTW, `InterruptedException` should be `IOException`.

Comment: Yes. `InterruptedException` has left from the previous version of the program where I've used `Thread.wait()` instead of `System.in.read()`. The result was the same: memory consumption.

Comment: Off-topic: What tool did you use to generate this graph?

Comment: jvisualvm. Located in JDK/bin.

Comment: Might be the Java VM. Just looking at the pattern it would make sense that that is the garbage collector firing off.

Comment: Haven't found this question before posting. Sorry.

Comment: Odd that this was closed without anyone stating what the "exact duplicate" was.