# Empty loop consuming more memory than non empty loop in java

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I was reading up on java performance tuning and ran into this.

When we run

```
public class test {
public static void main(String a[]){
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
            Double d = new Double(1.0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

JVisualVM shows a flat for memory consumption graph:

[image]

But when we run the below code,

```
public class test {
public static void main(String a[]){
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<100000;j++){
        }
    }
}
}
```

JVisualVM renders a sawtooth:

[image]

Why is this happening?
How and why gc triggering limit is changed for both the cases?

Comment: I think empty loop take more processor. So GC didnt chance to run.

Comment: Which version of Java? What parameters? Second test with empty loop should work 0 seconds, because java is not so stupid to run empty loops.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361902/why-does-an-empty-java-program-consume-memory

Comment: @Andremoniy - No. java can run empty loops (even after Escape Analysis was introduced i.e, after jdk6U23)

Comment: @Andremoniy Empty loops can have a purpose see nafas answer below, so of course java should run it.

Comment: Do one thing. Run both testes *one after another* in the same method and by giving a warm-up run for each. *statistics* can somethimes be *misleading*.

Comment: I must say, this is an excellent question to with a simple example prove just how important it is to not make -any- assumptions when doing performance tests. Can we have the source you were reading this in? Was it the Oracle performance tuning article or a book?

Comment: Ok Ok, guys,but I can not reproduce this behaviour on Java 1.7.0.40 x64 on Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: how much time does an empty loop use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271147/java-how-much-time-does-an-empty-loop-use)

Comment: The second diagram is not reproducible. Which platform do you run the test on? OS, JDK version? Do you connect VisualVM locally or remotely?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your `v1 for loops`, your local variable, once it has exited its scope, it will be marked for GC as free to be collected, so every once in a while the GC will kick in and collect that memory.

For your `v2 for loops`, those empty loops won't be 'optimized away' by the compiler**, only after multiple calls, because the

> JIT triggers AFTER a certain piece of code has been executed many
>   times [1]

Regarding your saw tooth pattern, [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) has a very nice explanation about it [2] :

> If I'm not mistaken, part of the reason for this is that the monitor itself is forcing   the application to create temporary objects that contain information about the state of garbage-collection and memory usage.

**  It is possible that they may never be removed because those empty loops are well known as being used as a waiting mechanism.*

[1] [Java: how much time does an empty loop use? - Simone Gianni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271147/java-how-much-time-does-an-empty-loop-use)

[2] [Why does an empty Java program consume memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361902/why-does-an-empty-java-program-consume-memory)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the optimization algorithm once the code is compiled. on the first case because you create a double every time without keeping a record of it.This would make the program use GC constantly. Thus the compiler optimize the code so less memory used. Empty loop is a special case, because many programmer use it to make a thread to wait. so compiler won't try to optimize that.

Comment: This is not true. HotSpot JIT is happy to optimize empty loops out when it can. C2 compiler (aka "server VM") can and does it. The second test case exits immediately on x64 JDK. But it seems that OP is running the test on C1 (aka "client VM") - this compiler is just not smart enough to remove an empty loop.

Comment: @apangin there are many different compilers. this is one of the optimization that "javac" uses. as the matter of fact it used to optimize empty loop as well, however they change it back due to some requests from gaming industry. (I don't know why but apparently some game producers use empty loop for waiting)